# What does the notation $\int_A$ mean, where $A$ is an event in a probability space?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I am used to seeing integral notation like this, which means the integral over the domain from a to b.

$$
\int_{a}^{b}
$$

But now I am looking at a statistics book that says "let A be an event" and then shows the probability of that event like this

$$
\int_{A} fx(X)dx = P(X ∈ A)
$$

How do I interpret the notation when only the bottom symbol is given?

Comment: Are you familiar with Lebesgue integration ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration))? Look in particular at [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Integration) and [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Domain_of_integration)

Comment: @ZevChonoles so it is integration over a subset? That is really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @bernie2436 yes, its over any set that has a measure defined on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are integrating over the set A. To do an integral, you don't necessarily need to lie in an interval (the points don't even have to be next to each other, you only need that the integral is computable). Intuitively (informally), you only need a set such that the set has "enough" points so that the integral makes sense (if you are interested [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) for an introduction to this concept).

So:

$$
\int_{A} fx(X)dx = P(X ∈ A)
$$

means just that, integrate the density function over the set A. If you want you can imagine its a summation, and you adding the infinitesimal points according to the density $f_X(x)$ over the elements of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You integrate over whatever the region is.

As an example, let $X$ be normal. What's $P(X>0 \text{ or } X<-5)$?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-5}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx$$

Comment: in my opinion that is not a good example because the set you provided is an interval. The OP seems to be unfamiliar to integrals of arbitrary sets. In fact, the example you provided is of the exact for he is used to, hence, the OP already knows what your examples means.

Comment: Edited to make a more complicated and hopefully enlightening example.